# Changing Pandas Dataframe Indexes

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I currently am working in python with a pandas dataframe in the format:

[image]
...

[image]

Such that every pair of values from column 0 and 1 have an assigned value.

I would like to make it so that I have a table with the values of column 0 on the x axis and the values of column 1 on the y axis with the corresponding value of the pair at the intersection of the rows and columns such that it looks like:

**5   40    52 ... x_n**

**5**   [1, 5.05, 8.55 ...x_n5]

**40**  [5.05, 1, 4.72 ...x_n40]

**52**  [8.55, 4.72, 1 ...x_n52]

**...**

**x_n**

Any help on how I would operate on a pandas dataframe to obtain this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Generally, you'll get better answers here if you share a bit of what you have already tried before asking for help.  As it stands, it sounds like you want us to do your work for you.  To get you started, you're looking for the `set_index` method and the `unstack` method.

Comment: Indeed, and also always try to provide some code which reproduces your problem.

Comment: You want a [pivot table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#pivot-tables-and-cross-tabulations). `pd.pivot_table(rows=0, cols=1, values=2)`